# end Kernel panic - not syncing error when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, 18.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my system, but whenever I select Install Ubuntu it gives me the photo below. The computer currently has Ubuntu 16.04 on it, but that was to make sure the computer did not have a problem with installing an OS. The install device I am using is a USB formatted to FAT32, using YUMI as my multiboot.

[image]

Comment: Same problem, can't even launch it from live CD. 16.04.04 runs and installs fine.

Comment: Did you checksum your iso ?

Comment: Any update here?... same problem during installation of ubuntu on pc which have already windows 10